# Solving initial value problem of homogenous equation $y' = \frac{7 x\,y}{7 x^{2}+2 y^{2}}$ using substitution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, homogeneous-equation

I am given the initial value problem

> \begin{array}{l} 
>   y' = \dfrac{7 x\,y}{7 x^{2}+2 y^{2}} \\
>   y(1)=1 \end{array}

where I must answer in the form of $F(x,y)=\frac{7}{4}$.

Here, I am also asked to use the substitution $y=xu$ to transform this differential equation into a separable differential equation in $u$. I am not sure how to go about doing this since I am not too familiar with differential equations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y'=u+u'x$ and substitute in you equation, then
$$u+u'x=\dfrac{7x(ux)}{7x^2+2x^2u^2}=\dfrac{7u}{7+2u^2}$$
and
$$\dfrac{7+2u^2}{2u^3}du=-\dfrac{dx}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{7}{2u^3}du+\dfrac{1}{u}du=-\dfrac{dx}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{7}{-4u^2}+\ln u=-\ln x+ C$$
$$\dfrac{7x^2}{-4y^2}+\ln y-\ln x=-\ln x+C$$
$$\ln y=C+\dfrac{7x^2}{4y^2}$$
set $y(1)=1$ so $C=-\dfrac74$ and $\color{blue}{-\ln y+\dfrac{7x^2}{4y^2}=\dfrac74}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=ux$$
$$dy=(u+xu')dx$$
$$y'=u+xu'$$
$$u+xu'=\frac{7ux^2}{7x^2+2u^2x^2}$$
$$u+xu'=\frac{7u}{7+2u^2}$$
$$(7+2u^2)(u+x\frac{du}{dx})=7u$$
$$7u+7x\frac{du}{dx}+2u^3+2u^2x\frac{du}{dx}=7u$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}(7+2u^2)=-2u^3$$
$$\frac{1}{x} dx=-\frac{7}{2u^3}-\frac{1}{u}du$$
Then you can integrate both sides to find an equation in terms of $x,u$
$$\ln x=\frac{7}{4}u^{-2}-\ln u+C$$
Then use this $u=\frac{y}{x}$ to rewrite it and substitute values in to determine the value of the constant $C$.

When $x=1,y=1$ so when $x=1,u=1$

Thus $C=-\frac{7}{4}$

$$\ln y=\frac{7}{4}(\frac{x^2}{y^2}-1)$$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2\ln y}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{7}{4}$$